Zero knowledge set membership resilient wrt dictionary attacks
Do there exist zero knowledge accumulators that are resilient wrt dictionary attacks?
What I mean is the following. Prover commits a secret value S to the accumulator A. A is maintained by the verifier. Prover does not have to show S in the clear in the commitment phase, and also in the proof  of membership phase.
Application that I have in mind is proving that H = h(S) comes from some committed S, for h(S) being a one way function. If during the commitment S was shown to the verifier, the malicious verifier then can brute force S by computing all h(S_i).
The RSA accumulator $W = g^{S_1*...*S_n}$ is not resilient under the dictionary attack because the verifier knows the set $S_1,...,S_n$.


Do there exist zero knowledge accumulators that are resilient wrt dictionary attacks?

Certainly, and many are in use right now in the cryptocurrency space; for example: Zcash and Tornado cash. Such that you can review the code that accomplishes this directly.
The way it's usually done in that particular setting (money tokens) is by having two secrets S1, S2. Commit H(S1 || S2).
Prove knowledge of S1 and S2 through ZKP and in the process also reveal H(S2) (aka nullifier) such that you cannot reuse a member a second time or else the nullifier will not be unique.
All commitments are public, so you need to prove a Merkle tree path to your particular leaf.
